# Post request speed and delay cause real-time audio information loss

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, audio

Previously tested on local localhost because there is no delay and network speed, so it can be done in real time, but after being loaded on Cloud server, the number of post requests sent is reduced, because the post request is completed longer, complete one during the post request, the audio has skipped a part of it, causing the audio information to be lost. It is equivalent to sampling at several points and cannot be real-time.
The server's latency is unavoidable, pinging, the delay is about 60ms, and the local is less than 1ms.

So I would like to ask if there is any way to avoid the front end to transmit audio data through many post requests, and my java background can receive.

Maybe websocket? (https)The type of my audio information is Float32Array, but I don't know how to receive it.(Many java examples receive String data type)

Comment: that is *useful information* - did you have a question about programming?

Comment: Sorry, I have added my question.

Comment: a websocket sounds good, of course, then you'll need help with both ends, the client and server